# Starting to learn Enum , property PTx

Tags: enums

Im new on C# and now im studying enums and im having this problem on property PTx.

error " 1   Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'EE5.Taxas' is less accessible than property 'EE5.Deposito.PTx'   33 "

what should i do?

namespace EE5
{
    enum Taxas
    { A = 20, B = 24, C = 30 }

```
enum Limites 
{L1 = 2, L2 = 5 }

public class Deposito
{
    private double Capital;
    private int Time;
    private Taxas Tx;

    public Deposito(int C, double N)
    {
        Capital = C;
        Time = N;
        if (N < (int)Limites.L1)
            Tx = Taxas.A;
        else 
            if (N < (int)Limites.L2)
                Tx = Taxas.B;
            else
                Tx = Taxas.C;
    }

    public Taxas PTx
    {
        get
        {
            return Tx;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Taxas enum public.

```
namespace EE5 { public enum Taxas { A = 20, B = 24, C = 30 }
```